# mod_rewrite - some requests being rewritten should produce a 404 but don't

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-404

I've been working on creating seo friendly urls for my site and have done this successfully with the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#redirect non www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

# Redirect any request with page=var to /var/ format
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.+[^/])$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.cfm$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1/? [R=301,L,NC]

# If not an existing file or directory rewrite any request
# to page var.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$ index.cfm?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

My problem is that because of the last rule (I think), any root dir request is made into a friendly url such as `/pagethatdoesntpointanywhere/` whether it points anywhere or not. Now I'd be happy with a 404 but it's not doing that it's just displaying the homepage.

I've also tried adding a blanket 404 rule:

```
# 404 files that don't exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .+ /notfound.html [R=404,L,NC]
```

But that makes all of the friendly urls 404s as well.

Could someone explain where I am going wrong here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.cfm` to display not found error page when Apache cannot find the file (replace `notfound.cfm` by your file).
2. In `index.cfm`, if value of `page` parameter is unknown (e.g. `pagethatdoesntpointanywhere`), display 404 error page (use the same/similar code as `notfound.cfm`). It is the right place to do considering your rewrite rules and the fact that you checking which page to display here anyway. Lots of products/frameworks work in similar fashion (for example: WordPress).

Use both #1 and #2. Number #2 will work for 1-folder deep URLs (e.g `/meow/`) while #1 will catch any other URLs (e.f. `/meow/kitten/` or `/meow/wuf/oink.css`).

Comment: Ok that sounds like a plan, thanks again LazyOne, I will head forth in that direction.